# Separation of Concerns design principle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my microservice written on spring-boot I have following DTO and Entity:

```
@Entity
class Order {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Product> products;
    
    // getters setters

    public Product getMainProduct() {
        final String someBusinessValue = "A";

        return products.stream()
                .filter(product -> someBusinessValue.equals(product.getSomeBusinessValue()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No product found with someBusinessValue 'A'"));
    }
}

class OrderRequest {
    
    private List<ProductDto> productDtos;
    
    // getters setters

    public ProductDto getMainProductDto() {
        final String someBusinessValue = "A";

        return productDtos.stream()
                .filter(productDto -> someBusinessValue.equals(productDto.getSomeBusinessValue()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No productDto found with someBusinessValue 'A'"));
    }
}
```

As seen both entity and dto contain some business logic method for taking the "main" product from the list of all product. It is needed to work with this "main" product in many parts of the code (only in service layer). I have received a comment after adding these methods:

> Design-wise you made it (in Dto) and the one in DB entity tightly coupled through all layers. This method is used in services only. That means that general architecture rules for layers must apply. In this particular case, the "separation-of-concerns" rule. Essentially it means that the service layer does not need to know about the request parameter of the controller, as well as the controller shouldn't be coupled with what's returned from service layer. Otherwise a tight coupling occurs. Here's a schematical example of how it should be:

```
class RestController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

    public CreateItemResponse createItem(CreateItemRequest request) {
        CreateItemDTO createItemDTO = toCreateItemDTO(request);

        ItemDTO itemDTO = itemService.createItem(createItemDTO);

        return toResponse(itemDTO);
}
```

In fact, it is proposed to create another intermediate DTO (OrderDto), which additionally contains the main product field:

```
class OrderDto {
    
    private List<ProductDto> productDtos;

    private ProductDto mainProductDto;
    
    // getters setters
}
```

into which the `OrderRequest` will be converted in the controller before passing it to the service layer, and the `OrderEntity` already in the service layer itself before working with it. And the method for obtaining the main product should be placed in mapper. Schematically looks like this:

> ---OrderRequest---> **Controller**(convert to OrderDto)
> ---OrderDto--> **Service**(Convert OrderEntity to OrderDto) <---OrderEntity--- **JpaRepository**

Actually, this leads to a lot of additional conversions within the service, some unusual work, for example, when updating an entity, now you have two intermediate dto (one from the controller for the update), the other from the repository (the entity found for the update and converted to intermediate dto in service layer) and you need to adopt the state of one into the other, and then map the result to the entity and do update.
In addition, it takes a lot of time to refactor the entire microservice.

The question is, is it a bad approach to have such methods in the entity and incoming dto, though these methods are used only in service layer, and is there another approach to refactor this?
If you need any clarification please let me now, thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all, you should change the naming, why?. Its simple, your first object should't calle OrderDto, if coming from a rest petition, call it, RequestOrder, its more simple to understand, the same with that "IntermediateOrderDto" just call it Order. The other thing its, not use DTO as mapper for change between entities, just create a converter, or a custom mapper, and use where its needed, if you want convert from the OrderRequest to the Order Pojo which its used on the service inject a mapper in the controller, and send to the service

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion in the names, there are other names in the real code, these names are just for example.

Comment: My suggestion is to make a class diagram for both cases (you can use a tool like enterprise architect to generate it directly from your source code) and you can see the dependencies between the layers in both case and you can compare